# Magento 2: How to specific HTML <div> decrease CLS score in Google page speed for Mobile view?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

i need to decrease CLS score for specific div tag for mobile view.

- **for ex. :** `<div class="product-info-main">`
- Screenshot Mobile View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHJaO.png
- Screenshot Desktop View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr9qX.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check to improve your CLS Score.

[https://blockthrough.com/blog/what-exactly-is-cumulative-layout-shift-cls/#:~:text=The%20CLS%20score%20is%20a,of%20the%20total%20visible%20area](https://blockthrough.com/blog/what-exactly-is-cumulative-layout-shift-cls/#:%7E:text=The%20CLS%20score%20is%20a,of%20the%20total%20visible%20area).

Comment: i have remove <div class="product-info-main"> tag after check same score is not increase

Comment: No worries , I will prepare the complete youtube video on this and will share which will help you. you can stay connected with us on https://www.youtube.com/createswowtech

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion i have found issue from css

Comment: @pankajparmar wat did you find?